# Filter elements by attribute values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I'd like to filter all elements with a duplicate attribute value.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements>
    <element pos="1"/>
    <element pos="2"/>
    <element pos="2"/>
    <element pos="3"/>
</elements>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/elements/element">
        <xsl:if test="@pos != preceding-sibling::element/@pos">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text() | @*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element pos="2"/>
<element pos="2"/>
<element pos="3"/>
```

Output (should be):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element pos="1"/>
<element pos="2"/>
<element pos="3"/>
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't get it. :-(

Comment: Identifying duplicates is usually done with grouping in XSLT 2 or 3 so look into https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="/elements/element" group-by="@pos"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:for-each-group>`

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use an XSLT key to group the elements and identify duplicates. Perhaps something like this:

```xml
<xsl:key name="elements-by-pos" match="element" use="@pos"/>
<xsl:template match="elements/element">
   <xsl:copy-of select="
      .[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('elements-by-pos', @pos)[1])]
   "/>
</xsl:template>
```

But as to why your code doesn't work as you expect, I think it's because this XPath expression doesn't mean what you think it does:

```xml
@pos != preceding-sibling::element/@pos
```

This expression does not mean "are there no previous `@pos` which are equal to the current `@pos`?"; rather it means "are there *any* previous `@pos` which are *unequal* to the current `@pos`?"

You are using the `!=` operator to compare a single `@pos` attribute with the *set* of `@pos` attributes which appear earlier in the document. The operator will return a `true` value if *any* member of the set satisfies the condition, i.e. if there is *at least one* preceding `@pos` attribute which is not equal to the current `@pos`. See the section on [Boolean expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans) in the XPath 1.0 spec for details.

Walking through your example:

- For the first `@pos` (whose value is `1`), there are no preceding
  `@pos` attributes, so there are *none* which are unequal to the current
  `@pos`.
- For the second `@pos` (`2`) there *is* a previous `@pos` whose
  value is unequal (i.e. the first `@pos`, whose value is `1`).
- The third `@pos` (whose value is also `2`) will be copied because the first `@pos` `1` again satisfies the `!=` condition.
- The final `@pos` (`3`) appears because *any* of the
  previous `@pos` attributes will satisfy the condition.

If you were to change that expression to `not(@pos = preceding-sibling::element/@pos)` then you would see the behaviour you want.